# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyIndex

Tags: java, exception, jackson, swagger

I'm trying to deploy a WAR application into a wls 12c (v12.2.1.0.0) and I'm getting the error above.

I'm using Swagger (for REST WS) and some pages supported by JSF framework.

The error happens only when I have a DTO as a parameter on a POST method:

```
@POST
@Path("/pesquisa")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Lista de Centros")
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, message = "BAD REQUEST"),
    @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, message = "OK")})
public Response pesquisaCentros(@ApiParam(required = true) PesquisaCentroDto dto){ 
    List<CentrosBean> lista = pesquisaCentros.pesquisaCentros(dto);
    return Response.ok(lista).build();
}
```

But if I put a String instead of PesquisaCentroDto all works fine...

I know that probably this is an compatibility error, but where? Here is my
[mvn dependency:tree result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5VXG.png)

The error stack trace:

```
Aug 18, 2017 10:46:15 AM BST> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyIndex(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/Annotated;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:82)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:753)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:263)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:53)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:601)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:343)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:895)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1422)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:454)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyIndex(Lcom/fa
sterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/Annotated;)Ljava/lang/Integer;

at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:363)
at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:127)
at io.swagger.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolve(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:99)
at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolveProperty(ModelResolver.java:106)
at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolveProperty(ModelResolver.java:71)
at io.swagger.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolveProperty(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:79)
at io.swagger.converter.ModelConverters.readAsProperty(ModelConverters.java:58)
at io.swagger.util.ParameterProcessor.applyAnnotations(ParameterProcessor.java:175)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.getParameters(Reader.java:971)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.parseMethod(Reader.java:897)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.read(Reader.java:298)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.read(Reader.java:150)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.scanAndRead(BeanConfig.java:235)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.setScan(BeanConfig.java:214)
at pt.gov.cic.rest.ApplicationBootstrap.init(ApplicationBootstrap.java:55)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:87)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:673)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:612)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:2053)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:2030)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1919)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3063)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1830)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:875)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
```

Any idea of what could be happening here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Error due to incompatible between  jackson core  and jackson-jaxrs-json-provider version.

Comment: but both are dependent from io.swagger-jersey2-jaxrs and both versions are 2.4.5. why are they incompatible?

Comment: I just confirmed by you with a version of respective jars.

Comment: Actually your root cause is "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyIndex(Lcom/fa
sterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/Annotated;)Ljava/lang/Integer;"
Hope you are not maintaing any library in your weblogic server regarding to Jackson.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! But I don't understand because I can deploy and run a REST only application (without any other frameworks) with the same io.swagger dependency and it works just fine including a custom bean as a parameter. The weblogic is the same too...

Answer (score 0):

The error was probably generated by incompatibility versions of libraries in weblogic and EAR package.

You can configure weblogic to load only jackson libraries are inside the package, by the [application deployment descriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/programming/app_xml.html#wp1064995).

weblogic-application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application
    xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.5/weblogic-application.xsd">
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>com.fasterxml.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```